# Is it possible to find linebreaks in cells where the "Wrap Text" function has been applied?

Tags: vba, word-wrap, split

Is it possible to find linebreaks in cells where the "Wrap Text" function has been applied?

It is possible to find line breaks in texts where Alt+Enter has been used to add new lines manually. The following code does it

```
InStr(Range("A2").Text, vbCr)
```

but it does not work i cells, where all linebreaks have been added automatically with the wrap text function.

I am trying to split the wrapped text to multiple cells with one line pr. cell. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no direct handle on where the text breaks in wrapped text (unlike carriage returns).  So you'll need to do some deduction in your code - as simple algorithm.  Below should get you started.  A couple things to note, the code below will not break at spaces specifically. Additional logic will need to be added for that.  Also, the most important feature of the algorithm is the inCharsPerColumn and intColumnWidth.  These two numbers set up a ratio of about how many characters will fit into the column of the given width.  Its an approximation, as different characters have different widths, so it is better to underestimate the intCharsPerColumn variable (say if it appears to be about 20 characters fit in a column 18 wide, enter 18 or 19 characters instead).  You'll want to play with that ratio:

```
Sub test()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim intTest As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intChar As Integer
    Dim intColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim dblRatio As Double
    Dim intCharsPerColumn As Integer

    'create ratio of approximate # of characters per given column width
    intCharsPerColumn = 20
    intColumnWidth = 18
    dblRatio = intCharsPerColumn / intColumnWidth

    i = 7
    Set myRange = Me.Range("B7")
    strTest = myRange.Value

    'determine actual characters per line (approximate)
    intTest = myRange.ColumnWidth
    intChar = Fix(intTest * dblRatio) + 1

    'cycle through text until each line is parsed
    Do Until strTest = ""
        'if the string is longer than characters per line
        If Len(strTest) > intChar Then
            'grab line of characters, and remove same characters from strTest
            strTemp = Left(strTest, intChar)
            strTest = Right(strTest, Len(strTest) - intChar)
        Else
            'grab the last characters of the string
            strTemp = strTest
            strTest = ""
        End If

        'place single line of text into current range
        myRange.Value = strTemp

        'increment the row
        i = myRange.Row + 1
        Set myRange = Me.Range("B" & i)

    Loop

End Sub
```